How to save CoAP server observable state in central memory for multiple server instances
I have an infrastructure where CoAP server (CoAP.NET library) receives message from client 1 and publish this message to subscribers of this topic (let suppose subscriber 1).
When client 2 sends message then it is notified to subscriber 2.
We need to scale out CoAP server to deploy it in mulitple instances and in that case each CoAP server will keep subscribers list (observers state) in memory) so the state is not in central location.
We want to save this observer state in some central memory or cache where all instances of CoAP server will use the same subscription state and notify clients accordingly.
Please suggest of we can integrate Redis or some other queue with CoAP.
